# Cant add a new element to an array (the value of a key) in mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a type called likes in a mongoose schema called users. Each time a user likes the post of another user , his userId gets added to the likes array.

```js
router.put("/:id/like", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!post.likes.includes(req.body.userId)) {
      await post.updateOne({ $push: { likes: req.body.userId } });
      res.status(200).json("The post has been liked");
    } else {
      await post.updateOne({ $pull: { likes: req.body.userId } });
      res.status(200).json("The post has been disliked");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

So everytime a user wants to like a post that has an id of id (and userId of whoever created the post) he goes to the route -

http://localhost:7001/api/post/:id/likes

and then sends his userId in json format. His userId should then be appended to the array corresponding to the likes key in the PostSchema which i have included below along with UserSchema.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./user");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      max: 500,
    },
    img: {
      type: String,
    },
    likes: {
      default: [],
    },
  },

  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 20,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      max: 50,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 6,
    },
    profilePicture: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    coverPicture: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    followers: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    following: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      max: 50,
    },
    city: {
      type: String,
      max: 50
    },
    relationship: {
        type: Number,
        enum: [1,2,3],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);


module.exports = mongoose.model( "User" , UserSchema);
```

Now when i try to do that , (postman API screenshot and database screenshot included below) it does not work and returns an empty array at response.

[databasescreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VUJx.png)

[PostmanAPIScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8tpj.png)

Comment: I think all you've really shown here is that your router is generating an error (since the response in postman is `500`). Have you printed and inspected `err`?

Comment: ohh i didnt sorry...let me check that real quick

Comment: @user20042973 it says TypeError: post.likes.includes is not a function

Comment: can you log `post.likes`just after you const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id) is it an array?

Comment: Sounds like your `findById()` might not be grabbing the doc as expected. You should troubleshoot that (and may also want to add error handling for situations like that in the future)

Comment: @cmgchess  it returns this - { default: [] }

Comment: so it doesnt fetch the correct one it seems

Comment: is req.params.id correct. is there a post with that _id

Comment: You should add Post schema to the question.

Comment: cmgchess
Yes there is.

Comment: There is no type in likes field in post schema

Comment: Fixed that but i am still getting this error  -  MongoServerError: The field 'likes' must be an array but is of type object in document {_id: ObjectId('6479c9c2ce9e09d5661dc30a')}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the following changes:

1-) Update the userId and likes fields in the post schema to have correct types and references.

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
        },
        //other fields
        likes: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User',
            },
        ],
    },

    { timestamps: true }
);
```

2-) Update the like route like this to handle post not found case if wrong post id is sent.

```
router.put('/:id/like', async (req, res) => {
    const postId = req.params.id;
    const { userId } = req.body;

    try {
        const post = await Post.findById(postId);

        if (post == null) {
            return res.status(404).send('Post with id not found');
        }

        if (!post.likes.includes(userId)) {
            await post.updateOne({ $push: { likes: userId } });
            res.status(200).json('The post has been liked');
        } else {
            await post.updateOne({ $pull: { likes: userId } });
            res.status(200).json('The post has been disliked');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

Note: you should also apply same changes for followers and following fields like I did in likes field.

Comment: undefined
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Comment: Can you please drop the posts collection, and try with a clean state? It should work.

Comment: If you can't drop, just create a new post and try to like that new post.

Comment: -SuleymanSah - the thing is i am kinda new into backend developement so i am following this tutorial on youtube so if i make a lot of changes i might not be able to follow along

Comment: Just create a new post with the updated schema and like that post, it should work, I tried it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a legend ,it worked... but how , what was the issue

Comment: The issue is that schema was wrong, types should be like in my answer. Don't forget to mark as answer, and upvote if not already done.